# Javascript function not triggering on button click

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var y = x.getElementsByClassName("child");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    y[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
}
</script>
<style>
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
</style>

<div id="myDIV">
  <p class="child">A p element with class="child" in a div.</p>
  <p class="child">Another p element with class="child" in a div.</p>
  <p>A p element in div with a <span class="child">span element with class="child"</span> inside of it.</p>
</div>

<p>Click the button to add a background color to all elements with class="child" inside the div element with id="myDIV".</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jmgrant15/3dcof7ox/14/

The "child" classes are supposed to turn red on the button click. Any thoughts why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: Your function is undefined because it hasn't technically loaded. So on jsfiddle you click the little gear and change the load to no wrap in body https://jsfiddle.net/3dcof7ox/16/ here you go

Comment: To put it a little nicer, your Dev Tools should be your first line of defense when debugging. You can open them by pressing F12 on Windows or Opt+Cmd+I on Mac.

Comment: @JeffGrant, StackOverflow has the ability to host snippets inline with your questions and answers. In the future try to use the snippet tool (`Ctrl-M`) instead of hosting the code off-site. ^_^

Comment: @EasyBB Thanks guys! I'm brand new at this, I appreciate your help! :)